# WindowsPhone Phonegap apps - scrips don't get loaded from the body

Tags: cordova, windows-phone-8, scripting, load

I develop crossplatform applications that target Android, iOS, WindowsPhone and Blackberry platforms.

I have an application where certain scripts are required to be loaded from the body. The application works fine and the scripts load properly on the Android and iOS platforms, but on the WindowsPhone 8 the scripts do not get loaded again from the body section of the html page.

Can anyone tell me if there is a work around. I need these scripts to be loaded from the body.

Thanks a million

Ex.
Page 1 navigates to Page 2

```
 <html>
 <head>
     <!-- LOADING SCRIPTS AND CSS-->
 </head>
 <body>
<div data-role="page" id="page2" data-theme="e">
    <div data-role="header" role="banner">
        <h1 style="text-align:left; margin-left:80px;"> <b>Page2</b> </h1>
    </div><!-- /header -->

    <div data-role="content" class="ui-content" role="main" >       

                    <!-- SOME PAGE CONTENT -->

        <script type="text/javascript" src="../LoadJSONLabels.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../Load.js">    </script>       

    </div><!-- /content -->
</div><!--PAGE-->
 </body>
 </html>
```

The scripts 'LoadJSONLabels.js' and 'Load.js' do not get loaded in the page body of Page 2, this happens only on Windows Phone 8. On the Android and iOS devices these scripts get loaded again.

Comment: Some more details, show what you got now maybe?

Comment: show me some code what you have tried

Comment: I have edited my question and added a piece of code

Answer (score 0):

Most likely there is an error during script file loading/execution. I recommend adding the following script in your main html page so that every JavaScript error is traced to Visual Studio console output (Ctrl+Alt+O).

```
<head>
     <!-- LOADING SCRIPTS AND CSS-->

    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.onerror = function (msg, file, line) {
            console.log('Error: ' + msg + '#' + file + '#' + line);
        }
    </script>
 </head>
```